# jquery variable using input field Name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a code like this:

```
var formFocus = formFocus || {
    spanElement: ".focusOnLoad form input[name="FirstName"]";
    init: function () {
       $(document).ready(function() {
          //come other computation
          $(formFocus.spanElement).focus();  
        });
    },
};
```

I am running into issues with this line: `spanElement: ".focusOnLoad form input[name="FirstName"]";`

I get an error at `name="FirstName"`

I tried escaping `"` with `spanElement: ".focusOnLoad form input[name=\"FirstName\"]";`Then I get Unexpected token ; error.

I can get the code working if I just use `.focusOnLoad form input[name="FirstName"]` as selector. But I need to use a variable since ist a shared code and some others without the knowledge of this part has to use this variable.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What part needs to be a variable? If you are having trouble nesting quites, just use single quotes: `spanElement: ".focusOnLoad form input[name='FirstName']",`

Comment: Maybe `;` should be changed by `,` ? You are enumerating members of an object, not statements.

Comment: @TodorSimeonov Yes, good catch. And, there shouldn't be a `,` after the `init` property.

Comment: You can use without any quotes [name=FirstName]

Comment: Todor, yeah..thats it! Thanks for the help. 

Now..I am gonna kick myself to missing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var formFocus = formFocus || {
spanElement: ".focusOnLoad   form input[name='FirstName']",
 init: function () { 
 $(document).ready(function() { 
 //come other computation 
 $(formFocus.spanElement).focus();
   }); }, };
```

You have here, you wrote

```
form input[name="FirstName"]";
```

Instead of:

```
form input[name='FirstName']",
```

The difference is: you terminated the line with semicolon instead of a comma, and also, you used double quote inside another double quote

Hope my answer helps

Comment: Yes, that is it. That fixed it.

Thanks for the help. Now..I am gonna kick myself for missing it.

Comment: I am happy it helps 